# c# contains method usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm adding a "search" functionality to a web app I'm working on and I have the following action method:

```
public PartialViewResult SearchEmployees(string search_employees)
        {
            var employeeList = _db.Employees.ToList();
            var resultList = employeeList.Where(t => t.FirstName.Contains(search_employees)).ToList();
            return PartialView(resultList)
        }
```

here I'm trying to filter out all employees that have a first name that contains the search string, however I keep getting a null list. Am I using the lambda expression wrong?

another question, is .Contains case sensitive? (I know in java theres .equals and .equalsIgnoreCase, is there something similar to this for .Contains?)

Comment: Have you walked this code in a debugger and verified that (a) `search_employees` actually has a value and (b) that it's a value that's in some of your employee names?  As a side note, you shouldn't be using `.ToList()` in that first line.

Comment: I've debugged but didn't check if search_employees has a value, I'll do that now, but yes it is a value in one of my employee names, thanks for the heads up

Comment: @JLRishe yes theres a value coming in with search_employees and its a value my employee has

Comment: To answer your second question, in the context you're using it (Linq2Entities) it is case sensitive - if you do var employeeList = _db.Employees.Where(t => t.FirstName.Contains(search_employees)).ToList(); (Linq2SQL) then it is dependent on your database collation as to whether it is or not as the where is executed in SQL.

Comment: This code should works fine. I think the problem is in your source data. `search_employees` or `employeeList`.

Comment: What is the value of search_employees and t.FirstName of the matching record you are expecting?

Comment: @Carl well i was searching for "jon" but the name is Jonathan, so I guess it won't find it since its case sensitive

Comment: @AbdulAhmad If you remove the `.ToList()` as I suggested, I believe it should become case insensitive. Have you done that yet?

Comment: @JLRishe yes I've done that, testing it now- ok tested, its working, thank you!

Comment: @JLRishe if you can put your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was the `.ToList()` in the first line.

.NET's `string.Contains()` method is, by default, case sensitive. However, if you use `.Contains()` in a LINQ-to-Entities query, `Contains()` will follow the case sensitivity of the database (most databases are case insensitive).

When you called `.ToList()` in the first line, it pulled down *all* of your data from the database, so the second line was doing an ordinary .NET `.Contains()`. Not only did it give you unexpected results, it's also terrible for performance, so please make a point to use a query *before* you use `.ToList()` (if you even use `.ToList()` at all).

```
public PartialViewResult SearchEmployees(string search_employees)
{
    var employeeList = _db.Employees;
    var resultList = employeeList.Where(t => t.FirstName.Contains(search_employees))
                                 .ToList();
    return PartialView(resultList)
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought you had to use `.IndexOf` in a LINQ to EF query. Glad to see `.Contains` is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following code?

```
public PartialViewResult SearchEmployees(string search_employees)
        {
            var employeeList = _db.Employees.ToList();
            var resultList = employeeList;
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search_employees))
                resultList = employeeList.Where(t => t.FirstName.Contains(search_employees)).ToList();
            return PartialView(resultList)
        }
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: thats basically my code... and if you look at the comments below my question, JLRishe's suggestion fixed the issue. This code will not work because you have the ToList() on the first line